Getting Size of CloudFront User Viewer Response Body
I want to know bytes transferred to the user by CloudFront in the response body. I want this for each individual user viewer response, not just an aggregated metric of overall CloudFront usage. Also, I'd like to get it immediately and programmatically, not in a delayed fashion, say, from a CloudWatch log. My goal is to bill each individual user a data transfer charge that's based on the data transfer charges that I pay, assuming that I've passed the 1TB per month free CloudFront tier, and I want to show these charges to them immediately so they can see them accumulate on a request-by-request basis.
I thought of attaching a Lambda@Edge function to the distribution's "Viewer Response" event, but I don't see how to consistently get the response body size from inside that function. Response headers are available in there, but it seems some responses have a Content-Length header and some don't. I don't see any way to access the actual response body in that function.
Trying to track the bytes transferred from each origin CloudFront is serving doesn't seem right, because I'm not charged for that, and, if CloudFront is caching then bytes sent from the origin would be way too low, anyway.
It seems there must be some way to recover the bytes that CloudFront is sending on a response-by-response basis.

One approach, although a bit complex, would be to configure CloudFront real-time access logging: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/real-time-logs.html
And specifically add the field sc-bytes to be logged. The real-time access logs can be sent directly to a Kinesis data stream, which you can then consume  with something like a Lambda function to manifest it to the user however you'd like (e.g. updating counters in DynamoDB or RDS, which are then fetched in a UI).
Viewer --> CloudFront --(realtime logs)--> Kinesis --> Stream consumer

If the content is cached, the sc-bytes will still be the same as it reflects the total number of bytes sent from the server to the viewer, including headers. In this solution, you do still need some identifier for the customer however, if using it for billing purposes.

While real-time logs look like they'd give me the bytes for responses that don't have the Content-Length header (e.g. responses that have been compressed by cf), that doc does say, "We recommend that you use the logs to understand the nature of the requests for your content, not as a complete accounting of all requests. CloudFront delivers real-time logs on a best-effort basis." So, since I'm trying to bill my users based on it, I'm wary of using it.
